# Can I configure Swagger UI to accept and empty array using Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I have the following Web API action

```
public IEnumerable<ItemDto> Get([FromUri] int[] itemNumbers)
```

`itemNumbers` are passed as

```
?itemNumbers=1&itemNumbers=2
```

I'm documenting it using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) (Swagger).

The API can accept an empty list (no item numbers), which is functionality I wish to have. However, the Swagger UI reports

> Provide multiple values in new lines (at least one required).

Is there a way to allow the `itemNumbers` parameter to be empty in the Swagger UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to try this

```
[Route("api/{itemNumbers}")] 
[Route("api/")] //when itemNumbers not provided it will be null 
public IEnumerable<ItemDto> Get([FromUri] int[] itemNumbers=null)
```

Comment: I need itemNumbers to be query string values.

Comment: Wise counsel. It did indeed work. I need to learn to embrace the unknown and go for it. Thank you.